# Xcode: Can you change views if your project isn't a View Controller project?

Tags: ios, xcode, view, modalviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I want to change views e.g.;

```
[example presentModalViewController:example2 animated:YES];
```

But can I do this in a single view application? May seem a silly question, but is there any way or anything similar?

Thanks,

James

Comment: What do you mean by View Controller project? Are you trying not to use UIViewController or UINavigationController?

Comment: I mean, when you go to create a new project, it asks you if you want a single view app for a view controller based app. I chose single view. Can I still create a navigation view controller?

Comment: Sure. You can create two dummy foobar projects using different templates and compare their differences, it helps you grasp a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new subclass of UIViewController and use:

targetView = [[<> alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:targetView animated:(YES)];

[targetView release];

In the header: add @class <> and take care of the variable declaration + getters/setters;

Will this work for you? I didn't know there was something like "single view application"...